# Equivalence relation partition

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Given an equivalence relation $\sim$ on a set $X$, the equivalence classes of $X$ form a partition of $X$. Conversely, if $\mathcal{P} = \{X_i\}$ is a partition of a set $X$, then there is an equivalence relation on $X$ with equivalence classes $X_i$.

Note: I am not looking for a solution to this.

My book said, "Suppose there exists an equivalence relation $\sim$ on the set $X$. For any $x \in X$, the reflexive property shows that $x \in [x]$ and so $[x]$ is nonempty."

My question is what if $X$ is empty? Then how can we say this?

Comment: If $X$ is empty, then the original statement is trivially true

Comment: If $X$ is empty, the *only* relation on $X$ is $\varnothing$, the empty relation. It’s vacuously an equivalence relation, but this fact is of no interest, and we simply don’t in general consider relations on the empty set.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So why are they claiming something which is not necessarily true?

Comment: @user19405892: They aren’t: the statement ‘if $x\in X$, then $x\in[x]$’ is vacuously true, since there are no $x\in X$ to begin with.

Comment: How can the empty set have an equivalence relation if there are no elements?

Comment: @Graham: It’s not necessary to assume that $X\ne\varnothing$, though in practice one usually might as well do so.

Comment: @user19405892: Because $\varnothing$ is a reflexive, transitive, symmetric relation on $\varnothing$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott They claim that $[x]$ is nonempty which is not true if $X$ is empty.

Comment: @user19405892: No, the claim is that **if** $x\in X$, **then** $[x]$ **is non-empty**, which is vacuously true if $X$ is empty, since the antecedent $x\in X$ is always false.

Comment: @user19405892: They are **not** assuming that $X$ is non-empty.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am saying their claim only talks about when $X$ is nonempty and says nothing about it being empty.

Comment: Fair enough.  $\forall x\in \varnothing : [x]\neq\varnothing$ *is* vacuously true. Every $x$ in the empty set has a non-empty equivalence class *because* there are no elements in the empty set which are witnesses to the contrary.

Comment: @user19405892: And I’m telling you that you’re wrong: everything that is said applies equally well to empty $X$.

Comment: @BrianM. Scott It seems to me what you said was that since the statement "if $x \in X,$ then $[x]$ is non-empty" has no effect on when there are no $x \in X$, the statement also holds if $X$ is empty.

Comment: @user19405892: Exactly: the statement is true for all $X$, empty or not.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Don't we have to think of the case that $X$ is empty separately?

Comment: @user19405892: It's probably a bit easier to think about that case separately, since the statement is true for a somewhat different reason, but the statement itself needn't distinguish that case.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Is there a reason why the solution left the case out that  $X$ is empty?

Comment: @user19405892: It’s wholly uninteresting and completely trivial. As I said, in practice one deals only with non-empty $X$ in this context.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott This is unrelated to my original question, but is there a reason why a relation in mathematics only deals with a $2$-tuple? For example, why not have an equivalence relation with an $n$-tuple?

Comment: @user19405892: Binary relations (sets of ordered pairs) are the most common (e.g., equality, $\le$, $\subseteq$, etc.), but it’s entirely possible to have an $n$-ary relation, i.e., a set of ordered $n$-tuples; they come up most often in [model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory). There aren’t enough of them in common use for a taxonomy to be needed, and some of the important properties that a binary relation can have don’t generalize easily. It’s not hard to generalize reflexivity and symmetry, but transitivity is another matter altogether.

Answer (score 1):

> How can the empty set have an equivalence relation if there are no elements?

It is vacuously true because there is nothing in the empty set to witness the contrary.   (There is nothing in the empty set at all!)

Suppose $\sim$ is the relation on the empty set.   Then:

- $\neg~\exists x{\in}\varnothing : (x\nsim x)$, so the relation is reflexive.
- $\neg~\exists x{\in}\varnothing~\exists y{\in}\varnothing: (x\sim y\wedge y\nsim x)$, so the relation is symmetric.
- $\neg~\exists x{\in}\varnothing~\exists y{\in}\varnothing~\exists z{\in}\varnothing: (x\sim y\wedge y\sim z \wedge x\nsim z)$, so the relation is transitive.

Thus the relation *is* an equivalence relation.

$$\begin{align}\forall x{\in}\varnothing ~&: (x\sim x)\\ \forall x{\in}\varnothing~\forall y{\in}\varnothing~&:(x\sim y~\to~ y\sim x)\\ \forall x{\in}\varnothing~\forall y{\in}\varnothing~\forall z{\in}\varnothing~&:(x\sim y~\wedge~ y\sim z ~\to~ x\sim z)\end{align}$$

---

And likewise, every element in the empty set is (vacuously) a member of an non-empty equivalence class.   There is not any such that this is not so.

$$\forall x{\in}\varnothing: {[x]}_{\lower{0.25ex}\sim}\neq\varnothing$$